# Gerador de chaves primárias em Django/Python com baixo risco de colisão e boa performance

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, postgresql, django, uuid

**GERANDO CHAVES PRIMÁRIAS EXCLUSIVAS NA APLICAÇÃO**

Eu gostaria de obter dicas de como gerar chaves primárias com baixo risco de colisão e que não reduza a performance das operações em PostgreSQL.

**Explicando o problema:**

Supondo que eu tenha 3 modelos: *Cliente, Produto e Usuário*
Em uma determinada aplicação eu gostaria de juntar todos esses modelos em uma mesma tabela de dados e poder fazer buscas através da chave primária, mas para isso cada registro deve possuir um identificador exclusivo. Neste caso, eu já havia pensado em utilizar UUID, mas são 128 bits e isso acaba prejudicando a performance do SGDB PostgreSQL. Por esta razão é que estou aqui em busca de alguma ideia que seja melhor do que as que eu já tive. Eu não preciso de um identificador exclusico universal, mas que seja exclusivo apenas dentro da aplicação.

Eu pensei em usar, com baixa possibilidade de colisão:

```
import uuid
import base64

def get_pk():
    pk = str(base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes))[2:-3]
    return pk
```

Desde já eu agradeço por qualquer dica!

Comment: Qual a versão do postgres que está utilizando?

Comment: O pseudo tipo [SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) satisfaz o seu requisito?

Comment: @Danizavtz eu uso a versão 12

Comment: @AugustoVasques não satisfaz, porque eu já uso o SERIAL nas tabelas separadamente. Quando eu faço a junção das tabelas ocorrem colisões. É lógico que eu poderia definir faixas de valores diferentes para cada tabela, mas estou justamente buscando algum método mais Pitônico para resolver o problema.

Comment: Veja esse exemplo se o ajuda: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/163f5/2 no caso é utilizado um [gerado de sequencias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) para criar as chaves, a cada inserção, independentemente de qual for a tabela, é gerado uma nova chave.

Comment: Boa alternativa, @AugustoVasques. Eu vou avaliar as alternativas, considerando segurança, performance e probabilidade de colisões, mas agradeço muito pela colaboração de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é solucionar o problema em SQL definindo um novo gerador de sequência com [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) e compartilhá-lo entre as tabelas criando assim a cada inserção uma nova chave primária exclusiva com [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-sequence.html) seja qual for a tabela assim evitando a colisão de chaves.

```
--Inicializa um no gerador de sequência.
CREATE SEQUENCE chave_geral START 1; 

CREATE TABLE Cliente (
    /*A cada inserção na tabela Cliente o gerador de sequência chave_geral será 
    incrementado e utilizado como valor para o campo pKey.*/
    pKey integer DEFAULT nextval('chave_geral') NOT NULL,
    nome CHARACTER(10)  
);

CREATE TABLE Produto (
    /*A cada inserção na tabela Produto o gerador de sequência chave_geral será 
    incrementado e utilizado como valor para o campo pKey.*/
    pKey integer DEFAULT nextval('chave_geral') NOT NULL,
    nome CHARACTER(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Usuario (
    /*A cada inserção na tabela Usuario o gerador de sequência chave_geral será 
    incrementado e utilizado como valor para o campo pKey.*/
    pKey integer DEFAULT nextval('chave_geral') NOT NULL,
    nome CHARACTER(10) 

INSERT INTO Produto(nome) VALUES('Produto1');
INSERT INTO Usuario(nome) VALUES('Usuário1');
INSERT INTO Cliente(nome) VALUES('Cliente1');

SELECT C.pkey AS ChaveCliente,
       P.pkey AS ChaveProduto,
       U.pkey AS ChaveUsuário
from Cliente C, Produto P, Usuario U;
```

<sup>teste o exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/163f5/2)</sup>

Quanto ao desempenho dessa abordagem é equivalente ao uso do pseudo tipo [`SERIAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html):

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

Já que pseudo tipo `SERIAL` é açúcar sintático específico do PostgreeSQL usado para a criação de gerador de sequência e atribuí-lo ao coluna especificada:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS integer;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashing o uuid vai gerar uma chave bem menor e com enorme possibilidade de não conflitar

```
import uuid
import base64

def get_pk():
    pk = hash(uuid.uuid4())
    return pk
```

Exemplo de saída:

```
>>> print(get_pk())

749691330465060769
```

**Nota**

Differença de tamanho na memória

```
>>> import sys

>>> sys.getsizeof(get_pk())
32

>>> sys.getsizeof(uuid.uuid4())
56

>>> sys.getsizeof(str(base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes))[2:-3])
71
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Paulo Marques! Eu vou aguardar para ver se alguém apresenta uma solução melhor, mas este método é bastante interessante. O meu objetivo é simples de resolver, mas não custa nada pesquisar por novas soluções.

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, poderia dizer o motivo para que eu possa melhorar a resposta?